# Battery backup is not good after the CM12 update on Micromax Yureka

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, micromax-yu-yureka

After updating to Lollipop CM12, my Yu Yureka is not giving not even 7 hours backup in balance mode. On KitKat CM11, it was giving 1.5 days backup in balance mode.

Is there a way to increase the battery life?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are rooted**, there are many apps and tools available to help you see which apps are killing your battery.

I have found [Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector&hl=en_GB) to be very useful.